# Format function pads inconsistently

Tags: python

The format function is not working correctly after 16 point precision

```
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.10555584)
'0.10555584'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.10555584124567896)
'0.10555584124567896'
>>> '{0:.26}'.format(0.10555584124567896)
'0.10555584124567896076030138'
>>> '{0:.18}'.format(0.10555584124567896)
'0.105555841245678961'
>>> '{0:.18}'.format(0.10555584124567896)
'0.105555841245678961'
>>> '{0:.18}'.format(0.10555584124567)
'0.105555841245669996'
>>> '{0:.18}'.format(0.10)
'0.100000000000000006'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.10)
'0.10000000000000001'
>>> '{0:.16}'.format(0.10)
'0.1'
>>> '{0:.15}'.format(0.10)
'0.1'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.12345678901234567)
'0.12345678901234566'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.1234567890123456)
'0.12345678901234559'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.123456789012345678)
'0.12345678901234568'
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(0.12345678901234567)
'0.12345678901234566'
```

Is there any workaround or another way to work with higher precision.

Comment: It is actually working properly, IMO. Some integers can not be represented in binary, so when you try to format the number higher than its digit size, it actually shows you the remaining part.

Comment: It's the classical probleme with floating points, you will be surprised to see that `0.1+0.2==0.3` is `false` but `round(1.5) == round(2.5)` is `true`. You can bypass this problem (that is common to all language) by using the library `Decimal`. Or if you want to compare two floatings points (since python 3.5) you can use `math.isclose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a format problem, but problem of floating point numbers representation. All current computers use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), and double precision (64 bits) `float`s have a precision around 16 digits.

There are indeed ways to process decimal numbers of arbitrary precision. That is what the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) module is made for:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d = decimal.Decimal('0.12345678901234567890123456789')
>>> d
Decimal('0.12345678901234567890123456789')
>>> '{0:.17}'.format(d)
'0.12345678901234568'
>>> '{0:.26}'.format(d)
'0.12345678901234567890123457'
>>> str(d)
'0.12345678901234567890123456789'
```